# User delegate protocol inside hashable struct\class

Tags: swift

I have a model with hashable protocol

```
struct Model: Hashable {
        let titleText: String
    }
```

I wanna add a protocol property inside it like this

```
protocol SomeDelegate: AnyObject {
    func delegateMethod()
}

struct Model: Hashable {
        let titleText: String
        weak var delegate: SomeDelegate?
    }
```

Can I write like this? Can I somehow hide a delegate property for hashable? I dont wanna write `static func ==` and so other functions inside Model

Xcode tells me

```
Type 'Model' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
Type 'Model' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
```

I understand that I need to implement some functions and so forth, but I do not wish to do it.

Comment: Well tough luck then. *Why* do you want a delegate in your struct in the first place? How about putting both it and the struct in a class?

Comment: ty for luck bro, I thought I found a solution) https://gist.github.com/Iron-Ham/d0eb72822f0965a3688241a70ec08f8c

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want to add a weak delegate property to your `Model` struct, you will need to implement the `Hashable` and `Equatable` protocols manually.

This is because the default implementation of `Hashable` and `Equatable` only works for structs that contain hashable and equatable properties, and weak references cannot be compared or hashed.

In addition, if you don't implement the `Equatable` protocol, you won't be able to use the `==` operator to compare instances of your Model struct, which may be necessary for your use case.

However, you can use code generation tools to generate the Hashable and `Equatable` implementations for you, such as using the "Editor" menu -> "Generate Hashable..." or a third-party tool like `Sourcery`.